# How to create an attention layer in LSTMs using TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I'm doing Natural Language Inference using LSTMs in Tensorflow and I want to apply the attention layer formulated as below from this [paper.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06664.pdf)
[image: Image from https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs224n/cs224n.1174/reports/2762054.pdf]

Tensorflow doesn't have an implementation of this to the best of my knowledge. It has an implementation of Bahadanou and Luong attention which is not something I'm looking for. Until now, I searched on Stack Overflow and found this snippet. It seemed to work well but it's not the implementation of what I want.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Attention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, return_sequences=True):
    
        self.return_sequences = return_sequences
        super(Attention,self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
    
        self.W=self.add_weight(name="att_weight", shape=(input_shape[-1],1),
                           initializer="normal")
        self.b=self.add_weight(name="att_bias", shape=(input_shape[1],1),
                           initializer="zeros")
    
        super(Attention,self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
    
        e = tf.keras.activations.tanh(tf.keras.backend.dot(x,self.W)+self.b)
        a = tf.keras.activations.softmax(e, axis=1)
        output = x*a
    
        if self.return_sequences:
            return a, output
    
        return a, tf.keras.backend.sum(output, axis=1)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'return_sequences': self.return_sequences 
        })
        return config
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to find an implementation of the attention mechanism introduced in the paper. But, I couldn't find it anywhere implemented in Tensorflow 2.0+. So, I decided to write the layer on my own and this is how it is done.

```
class RochtaschelAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, regularize):
        self.kernel_regularizer = regularize
        super(RochtaschelAttention, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):

        self.W_y = self.add_weight(name="att_weight_y", shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1]),
                           initializer="glorot_uniform", regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer, trainable=True)
        self.W_h = self.add_weight(name="att_weight_h", shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1]),
                           initializer="glorot_uniform", regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer, trainable=True)
        self.W_p = self.add_weight(name="att_weight_p", shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1]),
                           initializer="glorot_uniform", regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer, trainable=True)
        self.W_x = self.add_weight(name="att_weight_x", shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1]),
                           initializer="glorot_uniform", regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer, trainable=True)
        self.w = self.add_weight(name="att_weight", shape=(input_shape[-1], 1),
                           initializer="glorot_uniform", regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer, trainable=True)

        return super(RochtaschelAttention, self).build(input_shape)


    def call(self, inputs):

        y = inputs[:, :inputs.shape[1]//2, :]
        h_n = inputs[:, -1, :]
        first_term =  tf.einsum('ijk,kk->ijk', y, self.W_y)
        second_term = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(inputs.shape[1]//2)(tf.einsum('ik,kk->ik', h_n, self.W_h))
        M = tf.keras.activations.tanh(first_term + second_term)
        alpha = tf.keras.activations.softmax(tf.einsum('ij,lkj->lik', tf.transpose(self.w), M))
        r = tf.einsum('ijk,ilj->ik', y, alpha)
        output = tf.keras.activations.tanh(tf.einsum('jj,ij->ij', self.W_p, r) + tf.einsum('jj,ij->ij', self.W_x, h_n))
        return output

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'regularizer': self.kernel_regularizer 
        })
        return config
```

The implementation is as follows -

```
lstm_layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, 
                            kernel_regularizer=lam, 
                            recurrent_regularizer=lam, 
                            return_sequences=True,
                            return_state=True,
                            time_major=False)

lstm_layer_2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, 
                            kernel_regularizer=lam, 
                            recurrent_regularizer=lam, 
                            return_sequences=True,
                            time_major=False)

l2 = 0.0001
lam = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2=l2)
premise, forward_h, forward_c, = lstm_layer_1(premise)
init_states = [forward_h, forward_c]
hypothesis = lstm_layer_2(hypothesis, initial_state=init_states)
train_input = RochtaschelAttention(regularizer=lam)(tf.keras.layers.concatenate([premise, hypothesis], axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found 2 implementations of the attention from the paper you referenced on GitHub:

- https://github.com/borelien/entailment-neural-attention-lstm-tf/blob/master/python/network.py
- https://github.com/thundergolfer/reasoning-about-entailment-tensorflow/blob/master/implementation/networks/lstm_with_attention.py